# fzf / neovim : strange char in ls results

Tags: zsh, archlinux, fzf

in neovim v0.4.3, or `fzf` on Arch-linux, when I type `!ls`
the result of the `ls` command starts with strange characters.

```sh
:!ls
^[]4;0;#1e1310^[\^[]4;1;#629A3B^[\^[]4;2;#E79E22^[\^[]4;3;#D5B731^[\^[]4;4;#3D5984^[\
^[]4;5;#4D7091^[\^[]4;6;#68999C^[\^[]4;7;#b4c7d8^[\^[]4;8;#7d8b97^[\^[]4;9;#629A3B^[\
^[]4;10;#E79E22^[\^[]4;11;#D5B731^[\^[]4;12;#3D5984^[\^[]4;13;#4D7091^[\^[]4;14;#6899
9C^[\^[]4;15;#b4c7d8^[\^[]10;#b4c7d8^[\^[]11;#1e1310^[\^[]12;#b4c7d8^[\^[]13;#b4c7d8^
[\^[]17;#b4c7d8^[\^[]19;#1e1310^[\^[]4;232;#1e1310^[\^[]4;256;#b4c7d8^[\^[]708;#1e131
0^[\.swp
```

I am expecting

```sh
:!ls
```

same is happening with `fzf` tool.
I have no .zshrc whatsoever

See an [asciinema example here](https://asciinema.org/a/ENwGJxNUbdbjrNOH5CboYPxqr)

Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

The faulty tool was [pywal](https://github.com/dylanaraps/pywal/) and the line in my .zshenv `(cat ~/.cache/wal/sequences &)` which apply colorscheme to current terminal.

I have raised an issue [here](https://github.com/dylanaraps/pywal/issues/534)